# Is there a way to use Laravel api throttle on individual method inside a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am using api throttle in my `routes/api.php` (as you can see in the code) but I am wondering if I can use it in the controller on methods.

```
Route::resource('/user/{user}/post', 'UserPostController')->middleware(['auth:api', 'throttle:5,1']);
```

Comment: Whats the issue here? you can even specify the middleware for the single route of controller action..

Answer (score 6):

Better to use the routes to specify the middleware for the routes. Still you think to use / specify inside your controller you can define `__construct()` menthod in your controller like:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('throttle:5,1')->only('index');
}
```

This will work on the `index` action of your controller only.

For more details check the documentation [Controller Middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#controller-middleware)

Comment: @MarianPopescu let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 3):

you can override route  for example

```
Route::resource('/user/{user}/post', 'UserPostController')->middleware(['auth:api', 'throttle:5,1']);
```

> //add route after resource

```
Route::get('/user/create', 'UserPostController@create')->middleware(['auth:api', 'throttle:5,1']);
```

second way add condition in controller

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('auth:api');
   $this->middleware('throttle:10,1')->only('create');
}
```